# Graphing the linear equation $y = \frac{2x}{4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Well, I can understand how to graph basic liner equations, for example:$$y=2x-4 .$$

The $y$-intercept would be  $-4$, and the slope would be $2$. The coordinates could then be $(0,-4)$ and $(1, -2)$.

However, how would I solve a linear equation like the following?$$y = \frac{2x}{4}$$

What are the steps to find out the coordinates? The only relationship that I know that can possibly help me is: $$\frac{x}{4}=\frac{1}{4}x$$

Comment: You could write $y=(1/2)x+0$, if that helps... If you want a point on the line, just give $x$ a value, and compute the corresponding value of $y$. For example, set $x=2$; then $y=(1/2)\cdot2+0=1$. So the point $(2,1)$ is on the line.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
y & = \frac{2}{4} \\ \\
\iff y & = \frac{1}{2} + \;0 \\ 
 &\quad\; \vdots \qquad\vdots \\
y & = m x + b \\ \\
\therefore m & = \frac 12; \quad b = 0 \\ \\
\therefore & (0, 0) \in \;\text{line} \\
\end{align}
$$

And since $m = \; \text{slope} = \dfrac 12,\;\; (2, 1) \in \;\text{line}$, too.

Double check $m = \dfrac{ 1-0}{2 - 0} = \dfrac 12$

Answer (score 0):

$ y=mx+n $

$m$=slope

$n=y-intercept$

$-n/m=x-intercept      $

Answer (score 0):

**Strong Hint:**

The equation $y = \dfrac{2x}{4}$ is read as *the linear relationship described by multiplying the $x$-value by $\dfrac{2}{4}$*.

---

Since the numerator $2$ and the denominator $4$ are both even, we can simplify this fraction, meaning to *reduce the fraction to lowest terms*. To do that, we divide the numerator and the denominator by their greatest common divisor.

In symbols, the greatest common divisor of two integers $a$ and $b$ is expressed as $\gcd(a, b) = c$ such that $c$ is their greatest common divisor. By order of substitution, we consider $a = 2$ and $b = 4$.

Since $a$ and $b$ are even, their greatest common divisor is a product of $2$, namely itself: $\gcd(2, 4) = 2$

Therefore, we can simplify the fraction $\dfrac{2}{4}$ by dividing the numerator and denominator each by $2$.

Since the numerator is $2$ and the denominator is $4$, we simplify our fraction to $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Therefore, $y = \dfrac{2x}{4} = \bigg(\dfrac{2}{4}\bigg)x = \dfrac{1}{2}x$.

---

We cannot simplify the fraction anymore because $\gcd(1, 2) = 1$ and so this fraction is most simplified. It is *irreducible*. Now, we look back at the *general linear equation*, which is the general linear relationship of the $x$-value to the $y$-value. This equation is in the following form: $$y = mx + c$$ for which $x$ is the *independent variable* and $y$ is the *dependent variable*.

Since $y = \dfrac{1}{2}x$, then by order of substituion, $m = \dfrac12$ and $c = 0$. Therefore, $y = \dfrac12 x + 0$.

---

**What is the value of the slope?**

**What is the value of the $y$-intercept?**

**What coordinates would this linear relationship generate?**

Comment: and you felt the need to answer a 4 year old question with existing good answer because?

Comment: @Cursed I want to become a teacher when I grow up. And besides, I don't see anything wrong with the answer. If you did, well, you didn't ask the question. If the user who asked the question has a problem with it, I'll fix it.